# iOS8 View Pushed Down by "Personal Hotspot" or "FaceTime"

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode6

I have a simple Table View Controller.

For some reason when Personal Hotspot or Facetime is on (adds that top bar) it pushes down my view. What can I do to correct this? This is a vanilla Table View Controller so I'm not explicitly defining any weird constraints or anything.

My data in the table view is loaded after the fact via a web service call so I'm wondering if that has something to do with the view not updating.

I've seen a couple answers like this however I'm not sure what properties need to be changed: [iOS 4.1 Personal hotspot pushing down tabbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902405/ios-4-1-personal-hotspot-pushing-down-tabbar)

Here is a view showing the first table cell being partially covered.

[image]

**NOTE: If I open a modal, then cancel (close) it, the layout refreshes as it should and looks fine.**

Comment: I think this is the expected behaviour of the OS? Or you want your VC to be below the double-sized status bar?

Comment: Legoless I don't believe so. After opening/closing the hamburger modal it "resets" the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by deleting my Navigation Controller (root) and adding fresh.

Comment: What exactly did you do? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I had a custom Navigation Controller that was being used that I had previously messed with which was the issue (I had forgotten about it). I eliminated that and embedded it in a vanilla view that got it